# Keyboard merely plugged in greatly increases kernel boot time

Tags: linux, kernel, boot

Specs are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Z9R.png). I am using a K65 RGB. I am using the [ckb-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ckb-git/) package from the AUR to provide basic input functionality.

- With Keyboard and with driver:

Startup finished in 3.100s (firmware) + 5.648s (loader) + **31.800s (kernel)** + 5.664s (userspace) = **46.213s**

- Without Keyboard and with driver:

Startup finished in 2.873s (firmware) + 5.652s (loader) + **2.395s (kernel)** + 5.855s (userspace) = **16.777s**

- With Keyboard without driver:

Startup finished in 3.120s (firmware) + 5.654s (loader) + **31.735s (kernel)** + 5.583s (userspace) = **46.093s**

- Without Keyboard without driver:

Startup finished in 2.879s (firmware) + 5.653s (loader) + **2.279s (kernel)** + 6.008s (userspace) = **16.821s**

As you can see, the pure act of having the keyboard plugged into the computer **causes the kernel to boot about 30 seconds slower**. This is kindof rediculous.

While the kernel is booting it just says:

```
starting version 218
```

if I dont have it plugged in. I believe this is referring to the kernel booting.

If the keyboard is plugged in, then it says:

```
starting version 218
[    random number] usbhid 3-2:1.1: can't add hid device: -110
worker [66] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2 is taking a long time
[    random number about times two] usbhid 3-2:1.2: can't add hid device: -110
```

Then it boots to arch.

It is good to note that if I plug in the keyboard after it boots to arch, it takes about 30 seconds for the keyboard to be recognized (but I can still use my old keyboard).

Comment: What happened to the first gb of RAM in 6 minutes?

Comment: Please post the full output of `dmesg` after booting. Is `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2` the keyboard in question?

Comment: I have same problem because of my logitech mouse on ubuntu 15.04 (with systemd)

Comment: @Gilles http://pastebin.com/m8UgKi8Z

Comment: @Gilles this problem seems to have been mostly removed with the new kernel update.