# Plugged mouse increases boot time

Tags: boot, drivers, systemd

I was going through the output of `dmesg -e` and found that my logitech mouse is increasing boot time by around 7 seconds and my total boot time is around 45 seconds.

```
[  +7.334661] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.131604] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c05a
[  +0.000005] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 1-1: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[  +0.000002] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  +0.000128] usb 1-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
```

when I unplug my mouse logitech mouse and restart boot time is around 40 seconds.

from this I conclude that plugged mouse is increasing boot time. Why is this happening? what can we do to fix this?

link to file containing output of `dmesg -e` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10800099/).  I am on Ubuntu 15.04 with systemd

*another guy has same problem on arch linux [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192804/keyboard-merely-plugged-in-greatly-increases-kernel-boot-time)*

Comment: Is there something else connected on the USB hub? It can be that the mouse slows down a USB3/USB2 to USB1.1 and influences other inquiries.

Comment: @Anthon besides mouse there is ethernet cable and battery charger connnected